# Does harvesting Doughshrooms and/or Crumbspores grant you the extra cookies?

Tags: cookie-clicker

In the Garden, if you harvest a mature Doughshroom or Crumbspore, do you get the 3% / 1% (respectively) cookie reward, or does that only happen when letting these plants "die" after enough ticks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done some testing and confirmed that harvesting mature plants (Doughshroom and Crumbspore) doesn't give any cookies. It only gives cookies on decay.

I have also looked at the code and the function `onDie`, which adds the cookies, is only called after the tick decays the plant.

Comment: Is that based on your own testing, code evaluation, or something else? Or just an assumption? Clarification would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @MisterB I expanded my answer.

Comment: Excellent, those are two very useful confirmations! Thanks, @gre_gor !